# How can I extract URLs from plain text with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, url, plaintext

I need the Perl regex to parse plain text input and convert all links to valid HTML HREF links. I've tried 10 different versions I found on the web but none of them seen to work correctly. I also tested other solutions posted on StackOverflow, none of which seem to work. The correct solution should be able to find any URL in the plain text input and convert it to:

```
<a href="$1">$1</a>
```

Some cases other regular expressions I tried didn't handle correctly include:

1. URLs at the end of a line which are followed by returns
2. URLs that included question marks
3. URLs that start with 'https'

I'm hoping that another Perl guy out there will already have a regular expression they are using for this that they can share. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: regex is notoriously bad at handling balanced form.  Since URLs are based on balanced form, this is not the best application for regex.  I recommend using a state machine instead

Comment: Who told you URLs are balanced?

Comment: URLs definitely aren't balanced. That's not to say that it's necessarily easy to match them well with a regex, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried [URI::Find::Schemeless](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find) with the following text:

```
Here is a URL  and one bare URL with 
https: https://www.example.com and another with a query
http://example.org/?test=one&another=2 and another with parentheses
http://example.org/(9.3)

Another one that appears in quotation marks "http://www.example.net/s=1;q=5"
etc. A link to an ftp site: ftp://user@example.org/test/me
How about one without a protocol www.example.com?
```

it messed up `http://example.org/(9.3)`. So, I came up with the following with the help of [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Common):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use CGI 'escapeHTML';
use Regexp::Common qw/URI/;
use URI::Find::Schemeless;

my $heuristic = URI::Find::Schemeless->schemeless_uri_re;

my $pattern = qr{
    $RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme=>'https?'} |
    $RE{URI}{FTP} |
    $heuristic
}x;

local $/ = '';

while ( my $par = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $par;
    $par =~ s/</&lt;/g;
    $par =~ s/( $pattern ) / linkify($1) /gex;
    print "<p>$par</p>\n";
}

sub linkify {
    my ($str) = @_;
    $str = "http://$str" unless $str =~ /^[fh]t(?:p|tp)/;
    $str = escapeHTML($str);
    sprintf q|<a href="%s">%s</a>|, ($str) x 2;
}
```

This worked for the input shown. Of course, life is never that easy as you can see by trying `(http://example.org/(9.3))`.

Comment: @Sinan - This was a little more complicated than what I was hoping for but ultimately it was the only solution that correctly captured links that were missing the 'http://' part of the URL which I'm assuming will be a form many of our users will enter websites into our form. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

You want [URI::Find](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find). Once you extract the links, you should be able to handle the rest of the problem just fine.

This is answered in [perlfaq9](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq9.html)'s answer to ["How do I extract URLs?"](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How_do_I_extract_URL), by the way. There is a lot of good stuff in those perlfaq. :)

Comment: the link appears to be broken

Answer (score 4):

Besides `URI::Find`, also checkout the big regular expression database: `Regexp::Common`, there is a [Regexp::Common::URI](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2010010201/lib/Regexp/Common/URI.pm) module that gives you something as easy as:

```
my ($uri) = $str =~ /$RE{URI}{-keep}/;
```

If you want different pieces (hostname, query parameters etc) in that uri, see the doc of [Regexp::Common::URI::http](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2010010201/lib/Regexp/Common/URI/http.pm) for what's captured in the `$RE{URI}` regular expression.

Comment: Regex::Common is an awesome set of tools.  Almost every regex you could think of already exists there.  It's sad that people keep reinventing them :(

Answer (score 1):

Here I have posted the sample code using how to extract the urls.
Here it will take the lines from the stdin.
And it will check whether the input line contains valid URL format.
And it will give you the URL

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;

while (1)
{
        #getting the input from stdin.
        print "Enter the line: \n";
        my $line = <>;
        chomp ($line); #removing the unwanted new line character
        my ($uri)= $line =~ /$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-keep}/       and  print "Contains an HTTP URI.\n";
        print "URL : $uri\n" if ($uri);
}
```

Sample output I am getting is as follows

```
Enter the line:
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2565350/
Contains an HTTP URI.
URL : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2565350/
Enter the line:
this is not valid url line
Enter the line:
www.google.com
Enter the line:
http://
Enter the line:
http://www.google.com
Contains an HTTP URI.
URL : http://www.google.com
```

Comment: @thillai - This doesn't seem to work for URLs starting with 'https' or those missing the 'http://' like your 'www.google.com' example above. Any ideas on how to change your suggested implementation to successfully handle those cases?